# How to Get Id of Inserted Record via Apex

Tags: apex

How can I get the Id of a record which has been inserted using Apex?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? If you are using statement like "insert account", the Id of the account can be accessed by "account.Id".

Comment: better if you can share your code

Comment: If by chance you are using triggers and are wondering where the id is on a `before insert` trigger, it is not available as the record is not yet saved. You will only be able to access the id on an insert event within the `after insert` trigger.

Comment: This question has been re-asked multiple times. If there's an FAQ, this deserves to be on it.

Answer (score 19):

The platform allocates an ID value and sets it in an SObject's ID field implicitly as part of the insert operation:

```
Account a  = new Account(Name = 'Acme');
// a.Id is null here

insert a;
// a.Id now has a value set by the platform
```

[Fields are accessed](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SObjects_accessing_fields.htm) using just a dot and the field name; there isn't a corresponding getId() method. (The generic [field get method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) does work for 'Id'.)

So most of the time you do not assign a value to an object's ID field. An exception is where you have the ID of the object (perhaps from a lookup field on a different object) and want to update the object. In that case you can assign the ID and so save having to first query the object:

```
Account a = new Account(Id = accountId, Name = 'New Name');
update a;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using statement like "**insert account;**", the **Id** of the account can be accessed by "**account.Id;**".
Below code will give you an overview.

```
Account acct = new Account(Name='SFDC Account');
insert acct;

system.debug("Inserted Account Id = "+acct.Id);
```

**acct.Id** will provide the Id for the Account record **acct**.The debug statement above will write the Id to the **Debug logs**.

Please visit the below link for **DML usage** and using **Id** for subsequent logic(s) : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_examples_insert_update.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
Account acct = new Account();
acct.put('Name', 'Test');
Id AccountId;

Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(acct);

for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList)
{
    AccountId = sr.getId();
}

System.debug(AccountId);
```

Comment: welcome to the SF community. it is always good to elaborate your code with some explanation while adding as answer.