# How to get record ID after insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to get ID of the record inserted in trigger (after insert).

```
for(AM_Setup__c  i:trigger.new) {

     setupid=Trigger.newMap.get(i.Id).id;
}
```

I think i am doing that in wrong way.

Kindly Help me out !!!

Comment: `i.Id` is the Id of the record in your code snippet

Comment: duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57234/how-to-get-id-of-inserted-record-via-apex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an after insert trigger, the records have been given IDs so you can simply say

```
for(AM_Setup__c  i:trigger.new) {
     setupid = i.Id;
}
```