# How to get record id after it's saved?

Tags: apex

How can I get record id after it's saved? I need it to save additional information to another related custom object.

```
public PageReference save() {
    Participant__c  part = (Participant__c)controller.getRecord();
    controller.save();

    Participant_Address__c addr = new Participant_Address__c();
    addr.Participant__c = part.Id; //This line didn't work
    addr.Address_Line_1__c = part.Address_Line_1__c;
    insert addr; //Can't insert address record 'cause Participant__c is missing
}
```

Comment: duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57234/how-to-get-id-of-inserted-record-via-apex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Insert query you can use insertedobject.id which will gives you id.

For ex:

```
Account ac = new account();
ac.name = 'Test Account';
insert ac;

system.debug(ac.id);
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can use it. Can you show how, please? Thanks.

Comment: You can refer above code....

Comment: The problem is I can't insert address 'cause I need participant's id first.

Comment: You can try this:
//===========

Participant__c  part = (Participant__c)controller.getRecord(); 
insert part;   

system.debug(part.id);

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I was never able to find a direct answer with just using controller.save().  Spring '20 I was able to do

```
    controller.save();
    Participant__c part  = (Participant__c) controller.getRecord();
    System.debug('Id: ' + part.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

In visualforce page of this controller write following line:

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!Participant__c.Id}"/>
```

That line would work in apex.

OR you can do in code as

```
public PageReference save() {
    Participant__c  part = (Participant__c)controller.getRecord();
    PagerReference ref = controller.save();

    Participant_Address__c addr = new Participant_Address__c();
    addr.Participant__c = ref.getParameters().get('id'); //This line didn't work
    addr.Address_Line_1__c = part.Address_Line_1__c;
    insert addr;
    return ref;
}
```

Comment: The first line didn't work. I don't understand how I can use your apex code. I need to save participant's address to Address__c after new participant is saved.

Comment: @anwarabq updated the answer!

Comment: No, it didn't work. I think the problem is that when you're trying to get participant's id value it doesn't exist 'cause participant wasn't saved yet.