# Counter only adds first opportunity id

Tags: apex, unit-test, query, list, loop

I have a testclass in which I create serveral opportunities with several values when I system debug these the values are as espected. I use a counter to add the ids from the several opportunities to custom object invoice.

When I loop trough the invoices in debug I only get the values of the first opportunity, why?

```
    @isTest
public class UpdateAutoNumberTest {

    private static Map<String, SObjectField> officeToField = new Map<String, SObjectField>{
        'Amsterdam' => InvoiceCounter__c.Amsterdam__c,
            'London' => InvoiceCounter__c.London__c,
            'Los Angeles' => InvoiceCounter__c.Los_Angeles__c,
            'New York' => InvoiceCounter__c.New_York__c,
            'Shanghai' => InvoiceCounter__c.Shanghai__c,
            'Tokyo' => InvoiceCounter__c.Tokyo__c
            }; 
                @isTest
                static void test() {
                    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
                    User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
                                      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                                      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                                      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

                    Account acc = new Account(Name='TestName');
                    insert acc;

                    Contact con = new Contact(lastname = 'LastnameTest', firstname='FirtstnameTest', email = 'Test@test.nl');
                    insert con;

                    // Office determined by the opportunity
                    Map<String, Opportunity> opps = new Map<String, Opportunity>();
                    for (String office : officeToField.keySet()) {
                        opps.put(office, new Opportunity(Brand__c  = 'TestBrand', Account  = acc, Contact_at_client_side__c  = con.id , Person_who_gave_us_the_job__c  = con.id, PR_Worthy_Estimation__c = 'This could be award-winning',
                                                         Name = 'LoadedTest'+ office, CurrencyIsoCode  = 'USD', Main_Office__c= office, Amount=10000, StageName= 'Closed', CloseDate= system.TODAY(), Main_person_responsible__c= u.id, In_contact_with_client__c = u.id, Lead_generated_by_1__c = u.id));
                    }
                    insert opps.values();

                    // Add a varying number of invoices for each office so assertions more definitive
                    List<Invoice__c> invoices = new List<Invoice__c>();
                    for (Integer i = 0; i < officeToField.size(); i++) {

                        invoices.add(new Invoice__c(Name='INVtest', CurrencyIsoCode  = 'USD', Project__c = opps.values()[i].id));
                    }
                    insert invoices;

                    Invoice__c[] invs = [SELECT Project__r.name, department__c, Invoice_number__c FROM Invoice__c ];

                    integer i=0;
                    for (String office : officeToField.keySet()) {
                        System.assertEquals(office+'-'+0, invs[i].Invoice_number__c);
                        i++;
                    }
                    for (Invoice__c invoice : [
                        select Invoice_number__c
                        from Invoice__c
                    ]) {
                        System.assertNotEquals(null, invoice.Invoice_number__c);
                    }
                }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `for (Integer i = 0; i < officeToField.size(); i++) {`
where `officeToField` is Map in the following loop:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < officeToField.size(); i++) {

    invoices.add(new Invoice__c(Name='INVtest', CurrencyIsoCode  = 'USD', Project__c = opps.values()[i].id));
}
insert invoices;
```

> Use `for (Integer i = 0; i < officeToField.keySet().size(); i++) {`

**Update**

I have run the code at my DE, it takes values of each Opportunities.

I think, in the loop Invoice Name is `Name='INVtest'` so each time this name is same.

Comment: This still gives met the same result.

Comment: Inserting a new record always returns the value of the ID. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57234/how-to-get-id-of-inserted-record-via-apex

Comment: Refer my updated answer and can you post your debug log where it is taking first Opportunity for those invoices?

Comment: @SantanuBoral After a lot of digging I came to find there was a procesbuilder replacing my opportunity. Thanks for the help!